# Is this line of code too advanced for Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper-9.0

I was throwing together some stuff in C# a few minutes ago and wrote the following line of code:

```
private void ReportCheckState( String message , bool state ) {
            ( ( NovaEngineEditor )this.Parent ).EditorStatusBar.ShowMessage( ( message += state ? " Enabled." : " Disabled." ) );
        }
```

To my surprise, Resharper apparently *thinks* that the appending of the variable "message" will not be used in any execution path. This, however, is not true. It is used and it works just as expected. So did I actually find a way to outsmart Resharper? Here is a screen grab(Notice the greyed out text):

[image]

Here is an image of the final output being shown on the form; it does indeed work correctly!

[image]

Comment: Ok, it does work correctly, the new string actually is formed, but you don't use this value anywhere else in `ReportCheckState` method, so you get what you get.

Comment: @GrantWinney So...is this a bug? Or what?

Comment: Change it to `+` not `+=`. `+=` appends the value to the string variable. As you aren't using this variable later on in the code it is redundant.

Comment: Your code should be: `message + (state ? " Enabled." : " Disabled.)"` Edit: @alexw: beat me by 9 seconds ;p

Comment: Since you don't use assigned value further in the method, write it this way: `ShowMessage(  message + (state ? " Enabled." : " Disabled.") );`

Comment: I guess R# tries to say that result of `+` part of `+=` is useful, but assignment back is not (which is the case in your code - you never use value of `message` itself later)

Comment: @OrifKhodjaev I know the correct syntax, but it is true that my version works, and yet Resharper does not know that.

Comment: @Krythic ReSharper is telling you that you are unnecessarily assigning the resultant value to the variable. Although it works, it is redundant and not needed.

Comment: @alexw Alright, I get it. So it is not a bug. Damn, I was kind of impressed for a minute. =P

Comment: @Krythic: It's called learning :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break out the code

`message += state ? " Enabled." : " Disabled."`

is the same as

`message = message + (state ? " Enabled." : " Disabled.");`

The assignment is redundant as you don't use `message` variable again.

You really want

`message + (state ? " Enabled." : " Disabled.");`

Comment: @TyCobb Casting the statement should be necessary to make it work.